# select from one oracle database and batch insert in another oracle database using java

Tags: java, database, oracle

I am a beginner in Java programming.
I am trying to fetch data from  one oracle database table and inserting to another database table using below  java code and it is successful. However I dont know to implement the batch insert logic and increased fetch size in this code. Anybody can help please. My aim is to fetch 100 rows and insert 100 rows in one round trip instead of one by one insert. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Dbtodb {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
{
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:oracle:thin:@ipaddress1:port1:server1","user1","password1");
Connection con1 = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:oracle:thin:@ipaddress2:port2:server2","user2","password2");
String sql = "INSERT INTO test_GROUPS("+ "GROUP_NO,"+ "GROUP_NAME,"+ "BUYER,"+ " MERCH,"+" DIVISION)"+ "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
Statement statement = 
con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);  
PreparedStatement pstmt = con1.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM groups"); 
while ( rs.next() )  
{  
    int gpnum = rs.getInt(1);
String gpname = rs.getString(2);
    int byr = rs.getInt(3);
    int merch = rs.getInt(4);
    int divisn = rs.getInt(5);
pstmt.setInt(1, gpnum);       
pstmt.setString(2, gpname);
pstmt.setInt(3, byr);          
pstmt.setInt(4, merch);   
pstmt.setInt(5, divisn);   
pstmt.executeUpdate();
} 
con.close();
con1.close();
}
catch (SQLException e)
{
System.out.println("could not get JDBC connection: " +e); 
}

    }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but: you should not mix `SELECT *` with getting elements from the `ResultSet` by index. The order that `SELECT *` returns the columns in the `ResultSet` is not guaranteed. Either explicitly list the columns in the query string, or use the versions of `rs.getInt()` etc. that take column names.

Answer (score 1):

To fetch 100 rows at a time:

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM groups");
rs.setFetchSize(100); // <-- Add this to fetch 100 rows at a time.
```

To insert 100 rows at a time:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con1.prepareStatement(sql);
((OraclePreparedStatement)pstmt).setExecuteBatch(100); // <-- Add this
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM groups");
```

... the above will change the behavior of `pstmt.executeUpdate()`, so that it cumulates the inserts and only sends them to the database once the batch size is reached.

You'll also need one last little change to make sure your last batch always gets sent:

```
((OraclePreparedStatement)pstmt).sendBatch(); // <-- This ensures that any queued inserts get sent to the database.
con.close();
con1.close();
```

**Documentation links:**

- [Resultset Fetch Size](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/resltset.htm#JJDBC28621)
- [Update Batching](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/oraperf.htm#JJDBC28753)